# Powerpoint Text Will Only Decrease, Not Increase

Tags: windows-10, fonts, microsoft-powerpoint-2016

I am using Powerpoint 365. I have a slide that started as a "Title + Content" layout, and typed in my content, then decided I wanted a "Two Content" layout and converted it. I started typing in the right hand box, and noticed that as I added text to the right hand box, the text in the left hand box was shrinking for no reason. So, I selected the left hand box and pressed the "Increase Font Size" button (The A with the up arrow) and it did the opposite, the font size in the left box got smaller! Then I pressed "Decrease Font Size" (The A with the down arrow) and it continued to get smaller. Why are both buttons making the font smaller? What can I do to stop this?

Undo / Ctrl + Z was the only way to get my font back to the size it was before, but I still can't get it to the size I want.

Comment: This sounds like an issue you should bring up with Microsoft Support. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us

Comment: Try to start a new Two Content slide to replace the one that has problems